# HTML 5 file upload using java servlet access denied exception

Tags: java, html, file, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying the file upload feature, which seems to work, as the file appears where it should, in the C:/xampp/tomcat/temp folder. However, the response comes back as the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xampp\tomcat\temp (Access is denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xampp\tomcat\temp (Access is denied)
The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xampp\tomcat\temp (Access is denied)


Main.FileUpload.doPost(FileUpload.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root causejava.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xampp\tomcat\temp (Access is denied)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.&lt;init&gt;(Unknown Source)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.&lt;init&gt;(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:391)
    Main.FileUpload.doPost(FileUpload.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

What should I do about this, if anything?

Comment: have you checked permissions to the folder? Have you tried to create a folder there with the appropriate permissions?

Comment: the permissions are full access, as I am the admin (this is all happening on my computer)

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that not specified the file name when writing to the file system.
You should do something like:

```
String uploadPath  = "C:\xampp\tomcat\temp";
FileItem item;
....

String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
File storeFile = new File(filePath);
item.write(storeFile);
```

I hope this help.

Comment: That's what I was doing. For some reason it just stopped giving me the exception. I am not even sure of what I did.

Comment: @DarbininkaiBroliai Verify the file name is correctly added to the path, log or print the full path before storing.

Comment: You save me from stucking in this error since last 2 days. Thanks a lot. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This I hope it will help you. If you have different use case say it. I will try

```html
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
                try {
                    List<FileItem> multipart = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
                    for (FileItem item : multipart) {
                        if (!item.isFormField()) {
                            filename = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                            folder = getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "subfolders/";                           
                            File file = new File(folder);
                            if (!file.exists()) {
                                file.mkdirs();                                                                  
                                
                            }
                          item.write(new File(folder + "/" + filename));
            }
}
```